# ¿Como puedo obtener una columna de acumulados pero que dependa de condiciones?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito encontrar a forma de poder obtener un acumulado por cada uno de los registros (mi query actualmente devuleve los registros por dia), tengo algo asi:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(DAY, r.entrega) AS dia,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN (r.tipo = 1 AND r.idestado = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS cilindros_a,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN (r.tipo = 1 AND r.idestado = 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS cilndros_v,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN (r.tipo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS total_cilindros
FROM @tablaResultados r
GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, r.entrega)
```

El cual me devuleve resultados con la siguiente estructura:

```
dia cilindros_a cilndros_v  total_cilindros
1   1           0           1
2   3           3           6
3   1           0           1
4   0           0           0
5   1           0           1
6   2           0           2
7   2           0           2
```

Dese obtener el acumulado de la semana:

```
dia cilindros_a cilndros_v  total_cilindros acumulado
1       1           0           1           1
2       3           3           6           7
3       1           0           1           8
4       0           0           0           8
5       1           0           1           9
6       2           0           2           11
7       2           0           2           13
```

He investigado un poco y he intentado un par de cosas como

```
SUM(total_cilindros) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY RowId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS acumulado
o 
SUM(total_cilindros) OVER(ORDER BY RowId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS acumulado
```

Pero no he tenido exito porque no puedo usar el alias como parámetro de la sumatoria.

También he intentado anidar los `SUM()` para evitar el alias, pero en este caso me devulve un error en la sintáxis.

```
    SUM(
        SUM(
            CASE
                WHEN (r.tipo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END
        )
    ) OVER(ORDER BY RowId ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS acumulado
```

¿de que manera puedo conseguir esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez no es la forma más óptima, pero si es sencilla de plantear. Tienes una consulta ya resuelta, la idea es trabajar directamente sobre ésta, usando una `"COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION"`, esto es válido a partir de SQL 2008.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  DATEPART(DAY, r.entrega)                                        AS dia,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (r.tipo = 1 AND r.idestado = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS cilindros_a,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (r.tipo = 1 AND r.idestado = 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS cilndros_v,
        SUM(CASE WHEN (r.tipo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                       AS total_cilindros,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATEPART(DAY, r.entrega))               AS RN
        FROM @tablaResultados r
        GROUP BY DATEPART(DAY, r.entrega)
)
SELECT  T1.dia,
    T1.cilindros_a,
    T1.cilndros_v,
    T1.total_cilindros,
    SUM(T2.total_cilindros) AS 'acumulado'
    FROM CTE T1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T2.RN <= T1.RN
    GROUP BY
        T1.dia,
        T1.cilindros_a,
        T1.cilndros_v,
        T1.total_cilindros
```

Aprovechamos tu consulta exacta, y mediante un `LEFT JOIN` sobre si misma `T2`, armamos  un acumulado simplemente sumando las filas hasta la actual de `T1`.

Comment: He probado de manera rápida lo que acabas de compartirme y funciona, haré pruebas con una cantidad considerable de información para revisar el rendimiento. Gracias!